# Avoid tryCatch to return something in case of fail

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

in a tryCatch function, I would like to don't return NULL or anything when the tryCatch fail.

When you assign to an object an expression which returns an error if the object already exists his value isnt changed, e.g :

```
> x <- 1
> x
[1] 1
> x <- x + "a"
Error in x + "a" : non-numeric argument to binary operator
> x
[1] 1
```

And I would like to have the same behaviour using a tryCatch. So in this example after the tryCatch failed "x" is still "1" and not NULL.

```
f <- function(x){
  tryCatch(
    expr = {
      x <- 1 + x
      return(x)
    }, error = function(cond){
      message("error")
    })
}

> x <- f(1)
> x
[1] 2
> x <- f("a")
error
> x
NULL
```

Use `stop` do the trick :

```
f <- function(x){
  tryCatch(
    expr = {
      x <- 1 + x
      return(x)
    }, error = function(cond){
      stop("error")
    })
}

> x <- f(1)
> x
[1] 2
> x <- f("a")
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : error
> x
[1] 2
```

But even if I can modify the 2nd part, `stop` produces not rly helpful error messages, i.e the 1st part "Error in value[3L] :"

Is there another way to do it ? Thanks.

Comment: `stop` will return whatever string you put in it.  Can't you just replace `stop("error")` with `stop("non-numeric argument to binary operator")` if you prefer the initial error?

Comment: I know,, but with `stop` you still have that 1st part that you can't edit : `> stop("error")
Error: error`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want `stop` to not include the beginning part of the error message you just set the `call.` argument to `FALSE`.

```
f <- function(x){
    tryCatch(
        expr = {
            x <- 1 + x
            return(x)
        }, error = function(cond){
            stop("non-numeric argument to binary operator", call.=FALSE)
        })
}
x <- 1
x <- f("a")

Error: non-numeric argument to binary operator 

x
[1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks ! It make the error message more comprehensible in my case without the beginning part !